# Why is that for $x = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)} n}{p}$, where $p$ is a prime number, $x$ is always a positive integer?

Tags: prime-numbers

Here is a graph for the first few primes vs sum. [prime vs sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuSpD.png)

Comment: Does not work for $p=2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1} = \frac{(p-1)p}{2}$ which has a factor of $p$ for any $p>2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n=1+2+3+...+(p-1)=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$$

thus, your sum will become
$$x=\frac{p-1}{2}=\frac{\phi(p)}{2}$$

where $n \mapsto \phi(n) $ is the Euler totient function.

Comment: I'm sure the answer'er knows but for the OP, this only shows $x= \phi(p)/2$ is a rational number. For $x$ to be an integer, $\phi(p)$ would have to be even, so that you could cancel a factor of $2$ and get an integer. But $\phi(p)$ is even for *all* $n>2$. So this will always be the case. Equivalently, because $p$ is prime, $p-1$ must be even for $p>2$.